# Rclone copy only if files are "fresh"

Tags: google-drive, windows-backup, rclone

I run a simple script to perform an rclone copy to Google Drive of a RAMDisk each day, giving it the naming format of YYYYMMDD_name.  This works great, but is a bit wasteful because I don't actually change something on the disk every single day.

I would like to automatically check the source RAMDisk, and only perform the backup (of the entire disk) if *any* file, *anywhere* on the disk, has been modified more recently than the root directories (the RAMDisk is recreated from a local drive each day at boot, so the root directories always have a modified date/time of when the system last booted.  Anything modified after that date/time, is clearly newer therefore everything should be backed up).

I'm not all that skilled in windows scripting so I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this.  I specifically don't want to use sync as I want a daily backup so I can always roll back to any day (where something changed) should I need to.

I appreciate any pointers or tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to put a solution together with assistance from chatGPT.  Here is the final code once I got it working.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set datepath=20%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
set y=%DATE:~10,4%
set m=%DATE:~4,2%

REM Define source folder, destination folder, and list of extensions to ignore
set "sourceFolder=V:\test"
set "ignoreExtensions=.log;.data;.scid;.dly"  REM Add extensions to ignore separated by semicolon

REM Get the modification timestamp of the source folder (to the minute)
for %%F in ("%sourceFolder%") do (
    set "sourceTimestamp=%%~tF"
    set "sourceTimestamp=!sourceTimestamp:~0,16!"
)

REM Initialize a flag to determine if a newer file is found
set "newerFileFound="

REM Check files in the root directory of the source folder
for %%A in ("%sourceFolder%\*.*") do (
    REM Get the modification timestamp of the current file (to the minute)
    for %%B in ("%%A") do (
        set "fileTimestamp=%%~tB"
        set "fileTimestamp=!fileTimestamp:~0,16!"
    )

    REM Compare the file timestamp with the source folder timestamp
    if "!fileTimestamp!" neq "!sourceTimestamp!" (
        set "newerFileFound=1"
        goto :copyFolder
    )
)

REM Check files in subdirectories of the source folder
for /r "%sourceFolder%" %%A in (*) do (
    REM Get the modification timestamp of the current file (to the minute)
    for %%B in ("%%A") do (
        set "fileTimestamp=%%~tB"
        set "fileTimestamp=!fileTimestamp:~0,16!"
    )

    REM Check if the file extension is in the list of extensions to ignore
    set "fileExtension=%%~xA"
    set "ignore=0"
    for %%E in (%ignoreExtensions%) do (
        if /i "!fileExtension!" == "%%~E" (
            set "ignore=1"
        )
    )

    REM Compare the file timestamp with the source folder timestamp
    if "!ignore!" neq "1" (
        if "!fileTimestamp!" gtr "!sourceTimestamp!" (
            set "newerFileFound=1"
            goto :copyFolder
        )
    )
)

:copyFolder
REM Copy the entire source folder to the destination if any newer file is found
if defined newerFileFound (

rclone copy V:\test GDrive:20%y%/%m%/%datepath%_backup -P --copy-links 

) else (
    echo No newer files found in the source folder.
)

endlocal
```